# Snowflake ETL DATE to TIME using Informatica

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to ETL Using Informatica data from an Oracle Table DATE column to a Snowflake table TIME(9).
I only want the time portion of the Oracle Date column.
I cannot use TO_CHAR(<date_col>, 'HH24:MI:SS') as this converts to string and will not go into the Snowflake TIME column.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Informatica but I assume you should be able to do something like this. Extract it out of Oracle using `TO_CHAR(<date_col>, 'HH24:MI:SS')` which makes it a string, then when you insert it into Snowflake do something like `<string_col>::TIME` to convert to a TIME data type for Snowflake

Comment: Hi Barry, this query will run on Oracle, and return an Oracle datatype. As there is no TIME datatype in Oracle (correct me if I'm wrong), you may return a timestamp or varchar/string. Which datatype are you expecting to return? Why can a string not go into time column?

Comment: Neither oracle nor Informatica have any separate data type to support time. So you can not fetch time and loadinto Snowflake. What if you do a `TO_CHAR(<date_col>, 'HH24:MI:SS')` and try to insert into TIME column? if it errors out, you need to load it into a string column and use it like `<str_col>::TIME`.